# OS X JavaScript for Automation - cannot send commands to terminal without it already beingopen

Tags: javascript, macos

When I run the following code in OS X script editor with the javascript option selected, the "cd" and "cd desktop" commands work without issue AS LONG as I already have a terminal window open.

```
var Terminal = Application('Terminal');
Terminal.activate();
var targetWindow = Terminal.windows[0];
Terminal.doScript('cd', {in: targetWindow});
Terminal.doScript('cd Desktop', {in: targetWindow});
```

How can I achieve the same function without a terminal window already being open. I am trying to build a little app that will automate the opening of a virtual environment and the running of a Django server but would like it to work without a terminal window already being open. Thanks for your help!

I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can launch the application by importing `AppKit` then launching the application:

```
ObjC.import('AppKit')
$.NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace.launchApplication('/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app')

var Terminal = Application('Terminal');
Terminal.activate();
var targetWindow = Terminal.windows[0];
Terminal.doScript('cd', {in: targetWindow});
Terminal.doScript('cd Desktop', {in: targetWindow});
```